# Assign value from a txt to a variable to keep a counter - C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to create a simple counter that keeps the count of all the Competitive Programming Problems that I solve.
The issue with it is that I am trying to save the value to a TXT so then I just keep adding to that but for some reason, it is not working. It sometimes gives me random numbers or it adds a number to the side instead of replacing. For example, I start with 0 and if I add 1 it will be 01 and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int score;
int change;

int main(){
    ifstream input("score.txt");

    input >> score;
                 
    ofstream output("score.txt");     
   
    cout << "So far you've solved " << score << " problems!\n";
    cout << "Press 1 to add or 0 to substract\n";
     cin >> change;
    
    if (change == 1)
         output << score++;
    else
         output << score--;  
      
    cout << "Your current score is: " << score << "\n";

    output << score; 

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `score++` /  `score--`  are post-increment/decrement, i.e. the expression value is the score before inrementing/decrementring. You need `++score` /  `--score` instead.

Comment: Also you don't need the `output << score` after the cout

Comment: Close the file handle after you're done reading it. Then write to it. Also, just write a small bash script for this, seriously.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
ifstream input("score.txt");
input >> score;
ofstream output("score.txt");
```

should be this

```
ifstream input("score.txt");
input >> score;
input.close();
ofstream output("score.txt");
```

Close the file for reading before you try to open it for writing.

Change this

```
if (change == 1)
     output << score++;
else
     output << score--;
```

to this

```
if (change == 1)
     score++;
else
     score--;
```

Your code is outputing the score variable twice.

Comment: `ifstream output` typo?

Answer (score 1):

Changing this block of code:

```
if (change == 1)
    output << score++;
else
    output << score--;
```

to:

```
 if (change == 1)
    output << ++score;
else
    output << --score;
```

You also need to get rid of this line `output << score;` - Unnecessary line that causes more issues.

Then you will get your desired output.

Now, the reason for this is because any variable that has `++` or `--` after will have a *post-increment and post-decrement*.

So `score++` or `score--` will emit the original value of `score` and not show the new value, although it will increment or decrement, but will not show in your example (on the console screen).

While, *pre-increment and pre-decrement* `++score` and `--score` will emit the expression's result as an *lvalue* and show the increment or decrement.